Adding new indexes to Data Explorer Stack Exchange tables?
This is in regards to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, specifically, its query creator.
I am trying to run some queries about Stack Overflow involving CreationDate on the table PostsWithDeleted, but found that there aren't any (good) indexes that use that column. The best that I could find was the index IX_PostsWithDeleted_PostTypeId_Filtered, which has CreationDate right in the middle.
I was hoping to be able to use the CreationDate column so that I could calculate metrics for questions asked in specific date ranges. For example, average score of [Java] questions in October 2024.
Here is a slightly more taxing example -- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1875294/just-running-a-simple-test
--SELECT * FROM PostsWithDeleted WHERE id = 4;

SELECT
  q.ID,
  a.Score,
  "Answer is Deleted" = CASE
    WHEN a.DeletionDate IS NULL THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
  END
FROM PostsWithDeleted q
LEFT JOIN PostsWithDeleted a
ON q.ID = a.ParentId
WHERE 1=1
AND q.PostTypeId = 1  --q is a question
AND a.PostTypeId = 2  --a is an answer
--AND q.ID IN (4)
--AND q.CreationDate = '20241101'
AND q.CreationDate between '2024-10-29' and '2024-10-30'
--ORDER BY q.ID, a.Score DESC
;

When I tried to run this, it barely finished in time. Subsequent runs jump back and forth between barely finishing in time and timing out. This is just running for 1 day of CreationDates.
And I had to bully the db to get it to give me this, but here is the execution plan for the exact same query. Took me like 5-6 tries. I think I got lucky because some of the data was cached or something, idk.

As you can see, it only uses the PK_Posts index, which is the index that only has the ID lol. Aka, it is a slightly faster version of a Full Table Scan. Someone please correct me if I am wrong about that statement!
And of course, I am not asking for the index to be timestamp. Breaking it down by month is the minimum of what I need. Breaking it down by day is even better. Best case scenario is by hour.
I just don't want to do a full table scan when my query only needs results for one day/month out of the 15 years of data on the table.
As a suggested index, here is what I think would make the most sense. These are the columns I would have, ordered below.

CreationDate -- grouped by month/day/hour, whichever the DBA's are willing to accept.
PostTypeId -- useful for filtering down to just questions/answers/etc.
ID -- this is just to copy the format of the other indexes, feel free to remove this.

Also, here is a query that fetches the indexes that I am talking about.
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1875889/indexes-for-so

3 new indexes have been added on the table since I made this post.

IX_PostsWithDeleted_PostsByDate
IX_PostsWithDeleted_QuestionsByDate
IX_PostsWithDeleted_AnswersByParent

Here is a link to a query that fetches all of the indexes on this table. This link also includes the correct index column order, so that you can see column priority for each index.
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1875889/indexes-for-so
And here is the query itself.
SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexId = ind.index_id,
     ColumnId = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     OriginalColumnIndex = col.column_id
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 1=1
     AND t.name = 'PostsWithDeleted'
ORDER BY 
     t.name, ind.index_id, ic.index_column_id, ic.is_included_column, ic.key_ordinal;

With these new indexes, performance speeds up to <1 sec runtime.
Here is the execution plan.


Yep, this is pretty much it. Enjoy the new indexes!

@Slate Most definitely. Please tell whoever implemented this that we appreciate the rapid response time. This solved my problem perfectly. Also, since this answer answers my question, please feel free to update the tags accordingly. I don't know what to, but I know I needed a status-review tag earlier. Maybe a different tag once that the task is done? EdIT -- ah, I see you did, ty vm for that too.
